# Defining default vertical space for newline command

Tags: macros, line-breaking, line-spacing

Is there a way to alter the default vertical spacing for the `\\` line break command?

I am aware of the optional vertical spacing parameter for it, as well as the `\smallskip`,`\medskip` and `\bigskip` but I was wondering, mostly out of curiosity and not necessity, if this is possible.

Comment: Where do you use it?

Comment: The idea is being able to define it the preample of a class and then using it wherever I typically would be able to.

Comment: Yes, you may alter it. But it's probably best not to. You can easily define commands of your own, after all.

Comment: The word "typically" is a little concerning: it suggests you may be using `\\ ` far more often than you normally "should" be using it. Outside of tables, there's usually very little need to use `\\ ` directly. And inside of tables, there are better things to do than to fiddle with `\\ `.  Can you elaborate a little bit more with a concrete example?

Comment: I asked mainly out of curiosity rather than necessity. Nonetheless, I probably do use it more often than I should. I'm generally conflicted over the usage of `\vspace` and `\\[len]` when trying, for example, to set custom spaces inside a frame when using beamer. Should `\vspace` be my go-to command?

Comment: Beamer is somewhat non-standard and I insert space more often here. Even so, I rarely specify a particular space - `\smallskip`, `\medskip`, `\bigskip` etc. are generally enough. Why do you need to do this so often? The think about the `\...skip` commands is that they insert stretchy space and not just space, which helps things end up in reasonable places. (Normally, I'd say helps with page breaking, but obviously that's irrelevant for Beamer which is one reason this is a non-standard case.)

Comment: My impression is that you use ``\\`` for ending paragraphs, which is wrong. For separating paragraphs always use a blank line; for spacing them, look at the `parskip` package (but I can't recommend this practice). In case you just want to space two paragraphs, use `<blank line>\medskip<blank line>`

Comment: I generally do display such bad habits but this wasn't the main reason for this question. I wanted to see the basic form for altering a core command like `\\ ` in order to kick-start myself in an in-depth exploration of LaTeX. (Funny thing,  I bumped in to your answer on  `\reseved` registers). Thanks for the advice, I'll make sure to take it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update** Here is a solution (thanks to egreg's constructive comments)

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\@xnewline{\@ifnextchar[% ] bracket matching
                  \@newline
                 {\@newline[\z@]}}
\def\@newline[#1]{\let \reserved@e \vadjust
                   \@gnewline {\vskip \dimexpr#1+2em\relax}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta. \\
Mauris massa. Vestibulum \\lacinia arcu eget nulla.\\[1cm]
 Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent\\ per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Curabitur sodales ligula in libero. Sed dignissim lacinia nunc. 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You lose the possibility of adding an optional argument.

Comment: @egreg you're right. Let us wait for the OP's response.

Comment: Yes, this is what I originally asked for. Is it possible to alter it in order to include the possibility of adding the optional argument?

Comment: Hmm, this way you add a feasible page break point after the line with ``\\``, irrespective of using ``\\*``.