# Spacing of \newline and \\

Tags: spacing, line-breaking

Is there a way to set the spacing of the commands of `\newline` and `\\` for the whole document? (I am aware that I shouldn't use them, unless it is really necessary.)

Comment: What precisely do you want to happen?  Are you asking, for example, how to add an extra 6pt whenever a `\newline` or `\\ ` takes effect?  (Note that `\\ ` already has a different effect in multi-line math displays, and may have  different effect in tables than it does in text.)

Comment: Yes, I would like to add a few extra pt whenever I use `\newline` or `\\ ` in my text. Thanks for the note, I was aware of the tables but not of the multi-line math displays - I will keep that in mind.

Comment: \\ gets redefined a lot.  Even \centering and \raggedright redefine it.

Comment: `\\ ` is for making in-paragraph line breaks so the whole point is that it produces a normal baseline to baseline space, you can use `\\[5pt]` to add an additional space where needed.

Comment: Thanks yo everyone! With the help of your hints and the answer of @DavidCarlisle I was able to understand the case in my document and now see that no altering of the the commands is needed :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`\newline` and the default definition of `\\` do not set any vertical space at all, they just set *horizontal* space (to pad out the line allowing a line to be short).

```
abc abc\newline abc abc
```

is

```
abc abc\nolinebreak\hspace{\fill}\linebreak abc abc
```

So there is no vertical space specified: the line spacing is specified for the whole paragraph as `\baselineskip` and the value at the end of the paragraph is used for all the lines in that paragraph.

If you use the optional argument to `\\` eg `\\[10pt]` then it ends up being

```
abc abc\vadjust{\vspace{10pt}}\nolinebreak\hspace{\fill}\linebreak abc abc
```

Which means that line breaking for the paragraph happens as before, then after the line that contained the `\vadjust` (which is the line ending with `\\[10pt]`) an additional 10pt space is added.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation! In fact I found out that in my document must have been a different "error" so that `\newline` and `\\` showed a different line spacing than expected. I suspect that some glue was the trigger. If anyone is interested in actually altering the commands, I found the solution here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/266139/188437

Comment: Would it make a difference in the line vertical spacing between `abc abc \\[10pt] abc` and `{abc abc \\[10pt]} {abc}`

Comment: @jsbibra no, why would you add the braces?

Comment: as in this question-- https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/519071/distance-between-linebreaks-differs#519071

Comment: @DavidCarlisle What about `\newline`? Could you add vertical space with it? I have it in a tabular cell, where I can't use `\\`.

Comment: @Andyc you can use `\\[2pt]` in the scope of `\raggedright` or `\centering` in a `p` column, but you almost never want extra space between lines of the same  paragraph surely?? between paragraphs you can use `\vspace` or `\bigskip` or whatever as normal.