# Distance between linebreaks differs

Tags: spacing, line-spacing

I wonder, why I get different gaps between linebreaks, depending on if the linebreak, innitiated by `\\[5pt]`, is inside or outside the curly brackets.

Why does it matter? Shouldn't it be the same?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\textwidth=6cm
\begin{document}

{\raggedleft{02.2016 -- 09.2018}\par}
{\raggedright Testline to see the gap \\[5pt]}

{\raggedleft{02.2016 -- 09.2018}\par} 
{\raggedright Testline to see the gap} \\[5pt]

{\raggedleft{02.2016 -- 09.2018}\par} 
{\raggedright Testline to see the gap} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: You should never use \\ at the end of a paragraph.

Comment: Yes, I know. In this case, I had to do some special formatting in a much bigger document. But anyways, I wondered, why the outcome is so different...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The middle case is in error, what looks like a vertical space is actually the second (empty) line of the paragraph, the fact that is empty is why TeX screams at you

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 9--10
```

10000 is the maximum value of badness, so this is telling you that the output is as bad as it gets.  As it is a line of text not vertical space it for example would not be dropped at the start of a page if a page break happened after the first line.

The first `\\` is in the scope of `\raggedright` which means that for technical reasons `\\` is `\par` and `\\[5pt]` is `\par\vspace{5pt}` so it is not too bad at the end of a paragraph (although still poor markup)

But the second case is a "normal" `\\` so this does not end the paragraph just forces a linebreak in the existing paragraph, which then is followed by an empty line of text. You can see this by replacing `\\[5pt]` by `\\[5pt]zzzzz`  the vertical spacing will not change, but the second line of the paragraph will no longer be empty.

Note that `\raggedleft` does not take an argument so

```
\raggedleft{02.2016 -- 09.2018}
```

is the same as

```
\raggedleft 02.2016 -- 09.2018
```

The inner braces are doing nothing here.

Conversely in

```
{\raggedright Testline to see the gap}
```

The paragraph ends after the `}` by which time the `\raggedright` has gone out of scope, so this does not make a ragged right text it is a justified paragraph (but that is not clear here as it is just one line) the only effect of the `\raggedright` is to suppress the paragraph indentation.

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{6cm}
{\raggedleft{02.2016 -- 09.2018}\par}
{\raggedright Testline to see the gap \\[5pt]}

{\raggedleft{02.2016 -- 09.2018}\par} 
{\raggedright Testline to see the gap} \\[5pt]

{\raggedleft{02.2016 -- 09.2018}\par} 
{\raggedright Testline to see the gap} 
\end{minipage}\quad\vrule\quad
\begin{minipage}[t]{6cm}
{\raggedleft{02.2016 -- 09.2018}\par}
{\raggedright Testline to see the gap \\[5pt]}

{\raggedleft{02.2016 -- 09.2018}\par} 
{\raggedright Testline to see the gap} \\[5pt]zzz

{\raggedleft{02.2016 -- 09.2018}\par} 
{\raggedright Testline to see the gap} 
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```